# Spring JPA Data Repository failed to create bean for interface that extends CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am facing problems working with Spring JPA Repositories. I have created:

- a basic user domain class (`@Entity`),
- an interface `UserDao` which extends `CrudRepository`
- and a service layer implementation.

When I run the project, it fails because of bean creation exception of `UserDao`. As far as I understand it is the responsibility of Spring JPA repositories to create the bean for this interface (because it extends `CrudRepository`) and inject it wherever it is required.

This is the error I am getting:

> WARN :
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'UserController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private edu.sjsu.services.UserService
>   edu.sjsu.controllers.UserController.userService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: edu.sjsu.models.UserDao
>   edu.sjsu.services.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [edu.sjsu.models.UserDao] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)

UserDao.Java:

```
package edu.sjsu.models;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

RootConfig.Java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"edu.sjsu"}, excludeFilters={@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)})
@Import(JpaConfig.class)
public class RootConfig {}
```

`JpaConfig.java` I think I don't even need this if using Spring JPA but still i have created this config class following guides and tutorials.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("edu.sjsu");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }   

}
```

Let me know if you require other config and java classes to understand the situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `basePackages` in `EnableJpaRepositories`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "edu.sjsu.models")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig { ... }
```

By default, `EnableJpaRepositories` will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories. Since, i'm guessing, your configuration and repository classes are in different packages, you should tell Spring Data JPA which base packages to scan in order to find JPA repositories.

Comment: I have explicitly set packages to scan as    factory.setPackagesToScan("edu.sjsu");

Comment: That's for your entities. Those are annotated with `@Entity`.

Comment: It worked. One additional thing that I had to do is to remove additional dependency hibernate-jpa-2.0-api from pom because <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> was already compiling hibernate-jpa-2.1-api               Thanks Ali

Comment: Ali - Could you please guide on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305162/unable-to-use-repository-class-of-spring-data-jpa-on-a-class-method-in-quartz-wh?