# Unable to use Repository class of spring data jpa on a class method in Quartz why?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing `multiple-jobs-in-quartz-spring-example` which is combination of Spring + Quartz + Spring Data JPA.  I'm looking to developed a code which will run in 5 sec, it will hit to DB and fetches a records from DB.

I am close to making it working but I see small problem. In my JobA.class, why don't I get an instance of CustomerRepository.java? It's always null and thats why code unable to hit to DB.

Source code at: [http://www.github.com/test512/multiple-jobs-in-quartz-spring-example.gi‌​t](http://www.github.com/test512/multiple-jobs-in-quartz-spring-example.gi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bt).

**JobA.java**

```
@Service
public class JobA extends QuartzJobBean {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository = null;
    
    @Autowired
    public JobA(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }
    public JobA() { }
    
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext executionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~ Job A is runing ~~~~~~~~");
        Trigger trigger = executionContext.getTrigger();
        System.out.println(trigger.getPreviousFireTime());
        System.out.println(trigger.getNextFireTime());
        getCustomerList();
    }
    
    private List<Customer> getCustomerList(){
        List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll();
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println("ID : "+customer.getId());
            System.out.println("NAME : "+customer.getName());
            System.out.println("STATUS : "+customer.getStatus());
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;
    
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

**CustomerRepository.java**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{

}
```

**dataSourceContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">
        
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>
    
    <!-- <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="true">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database> -->
    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driver.class.name}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.username}" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mkyong.*"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**Spring-Quartz.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:dataSourceContext.xml"/>
    
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mkyong.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="jobA" class="com.mkyong.job.JobA" />
    <bean id="jobB" class="com.mkyong.job.JobB" />
    <bean id="jobC" class="com.mkyong.job.JobC" />
    <bean id="autowiredA" class="com.mkyong.job.JobASpringBeanJobFactory" />

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~ Quartz Job ~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <bean name="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.mkyong.job.JobA" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="JobB" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.mkyong.job.JobB" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean name="JobC" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.mkyong.job.JobC" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~ Cron Trigger, run every 5 seconds ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <bean id="cronTriggerJobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobA" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="cronTriggerJobB" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobB" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="cronTriggerJobC" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobC" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  Scheduler bean Factory   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobFactory" ref="autowiredA"/> 
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTriggerJobA" />
                <!-- <ref bean="cronTriggerJobB" />
                <ref bean="cronTriggerJobC" /> -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**JobASpringBeanJobFactory.java**

```
public class JobASpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Quartz.xml");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the following link http://codrspace.com/Khovansa/spring-quartz-with-a-database/ should help.

Quoting from the above link,

> Quartz creates a new job instance on each invocation. It means that Quartz jobs are not regular Spring beans and we can't expect the Spring magic to take an effect automatically (and Spring's 'JobDetailFactoryBean' is not smart enough to do it for us). So we'll have to implement our own job factory that would overwrite the default SpringBeanJobFactory.

So you need to have a `custom  SpringBeanJobFactory` by `extending SpringBeanJobFactory & implementing ApplicationContextAware` and finally invoke `beanFactory.autowireBean(job)`

Comment: Assuming I interpreted your comment right, I believe you have access to update the `Spring-Quartz.xml` XML. If so, you need to add a new `custom SpringBeanJobFactory by extending SpringBeanJobFactory & implementing ApplicationContextAware`. Add this as a bean in `Spring-Quartz.xml` and refer this bean as `jobFactory` property in the existing `<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">`.

Comment: `customerRepository` is null because **Quartz jobs are not regular Spring beans and we can't expect the Spring to do autowiring for them.**. So once you create a custom `SpringBeanJobFactory` and call `beanFactory.autowireBean(job)` from there it will take care of injecting the `customerRepository`. Along with the above link you can refer to [https://gist.github.com/jelies/5085593](https://gist.github.com/jelies/5085593) for a sample code.

Comment: I see that now you have a custom SpringBeanJobFactory named `JobASpringBeanJobFactory`. You need to add this bean in your `Spring-Quartz.xml` say `<bean id="autoWiredJobFactory" class="com.mykong.job.JobASpringBeanJobFactory"/>` and inject it into your existing `<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">...` definition by adding a property `<property name="jobFactory" ref="autoWiredJobFactory"/>`

Comment: It is saying `ClassNotFound`. The package name is wrong in the Spring-Quartz.xml file. Replace `com.mykong.job` with `com.mkyong.job` for bean definition `JobASpringBeanJobFactory.

Comment: Code working fine now. Thanks for great help. We don't need to use the Constructor Auto wiring now..Simple Autowiring works